# Change state depending on Country function in Service

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do a simple change state based on country function `countryChange()`. Initially everything worked fine when I had the function in the controller, but now I'm moving the function into a service, and I'm not too sure what's the best way to implement it without using `$rootScope`. Please see below:-

Service:

```
angular.module('core').service('FormService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var _this = this;

    _this.dropdownData = {
        countries: {
            {
                'id': 'cutomeId-001',
                'name': 'Austria',
                'states': {
                    {
                        'state_id': 's1',
                        'state_name': 'state1', 
                    },{
                        'state_id': 's2',
                        'state_name': 'state2', 
                    }
                }
            }, {
                'id': 'cutomeId-002',
                'name': 'Australia',
                'states': {
                    {
                        'state_id': 's1',
                        'state_name': 'state1', 
                    },{
                        'state_id': 's2',
                        'state_name': 'state2', 
                    },{
                        'state_id': 's3',
                        'state_name': 'state3', 
                    }
                }
            }, {
                //etc
            }
        }
    }

    _this.countryChange = function(countryId) {
        _this.dropdownData.countries.forEach(function(value){
            if(value.id === countryId) {

                // Originally in controller: 
                // $scope.states = value.states;
                // Not sure how to implement this in service

            }
        });
    };

}]);
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('core').controller('controller', ['$scope', 'FormService', function($scope, FormService) {
    $scope.states = {};
    $scope.countryChange = FormService.countryChange;

}]);
```

HTML:

```
<select name="country" ng-model="countryModel" id="input-country" class="form-control" required-message="'Country is required.'" ng-change="countryChange(countryModel)">
    <option value="">-- Select a country --</option>
    <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="statesModel">
    <option ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state.state_id}}">{{state.state_name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Unrelated, stylistic comment: since FormService is not a constructor function, it should be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your service class, replace the commented if block with this:

```
        if(value.id === countryId) {
           return value.states;
        }
```

Now in your controller:

```
$scope.countryChange = function(countryModel) {
  $scope.states = FormService.countryChange(countryModel);
}
```

Should work for you